# using asp.net code in a asp.net file (Response.write by another aspx)

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a asp.net file called header.aspx and which is a part of index.aspx, here is the code of the index.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="index" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <% Response.WriteFile("header.aspx"); %>
    <% Response.WriteFile("body.aspx"); %>
    <form runat="server">
    <%= content %>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

in header.aspx :

```
        <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="style1">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="images/Banner.jpg" width="990" height="150" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/HomeTopMenu.jpg" width="140" height="30" /><img src="images/AboutTopMenu.jpg" width="140" height="30" /><img src="images/PublicationTopMenu.jpg" width="195" height="30" /><img src="images/FormTopMenu.jpg" width="205" height="30" /><img src="images/LinkTopMenu.jpg" width="160" height="30" /><img src="images/ContactTopMenu.jpg" width="150" height="30" />
            <% Response.Write("abc");  %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    </form>
```

when i run the index.aspx file, the <% Response.Write("abc");  %> is displayed as plain text...

how to use asp.net code in header.aspx?

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to solve? Response.Write is working as intended there http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `Response.WriteFile("header.aspx")`, try using `Server.Execute("header.aspx")`.  This will actually run the `header.aspx` file.  Using Response.WriteFile gets the actual contents of the file, and does not execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to implement a master-page concept here. 
ASP.Net offers an easier way to do this, the following link may help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.100).aspx